# How can I delete regex substrings in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, text-processing

How can I delete a substring which starts with `@` and ends with a blank space in Python?
Also I want to remove all the  sequences starting with `http`, e.g.:

```
Input  "ABC @XYZ ABC @Python ABC http://www.stackoverflow.com ABC"
Output "ABC ABC ABC ABC"
```

Comment: Have you heard about regular expressions? https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: @freakish I think he did, since the title mentions them.

Comment: Oh, missed that. Then the next question is: what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex `sub` method and replace with the empty string `''`:

```
import re
input = 'ABC @XYZ ABC @Python ABC http://www.stackoverflow.com ABC'
output = re.sub(r'(http|@)\S*\s', '', input) 
print output  # 'ABC ABC ABC ABC'
```